# How to close running wix installer?

Tags: wix, wix3.7, wix3.8

I have created the wix installer for shipping file in C drive.When i run .msi file , I tried call one custom action before file shipping.In custom action following code i used .

Custom Action code :

```
            bool isElevated;
            WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
            isElevated = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
            if (!isElevated)
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("CustomAction is not running admode , so please refer online ?", "Admin Alert ", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Process.Start("Same Web site link");
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }
```

Above custom action working fine.If custom action not run admin mode successfully message box shown. If i select no option in message box wix installer closed , but file are shipped.So please tell me , How to stop the wix installer using C# ?

Comment: When are you scheduling this custom action?

Comment: Hi Brian , I have scheduling above custom action,before msi installer .  example :    <Binary Id="Checkadmin" SourceFile="F:\Work\SVN\BigData\Wix Burn\CustomAction\adminMode\bin\Release\adminMode.CA.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="CheckAdmin" BinaryKey="Checkadmin" DllEntry="Checkadmin" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="yes" Return="ignore" />                                                                                                                                         <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CheckAdmin" Sequence="1">NOT Installed</Custom> </InstallExecuteSequence>

Answer (score 2):

If you require the install to be elevated, just say InstallPrivileges = elevated in your WiX. There's no need to write code to check for it. Or check the state of the Privileged property in the execute sequence:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370852(v=vs.85).aspx

If you want a custom action to run elevated then it must be in the execute sequence and marked deferred and noimpersonate=true and the package has InstallScope=perMachine.

So you can arrange for the install to be elevated and there is no need to do any checking at all and no need to for you to prevent the install. Alternatively if you require an admin to do the install there are options that use the AdminUser property and MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367545(v=vs.85).aspx

You'd declare that MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION in your source with a value of 1 as the documentation says. The use the Privileged property as a launch condition. The setup will then not start unless the user is admin. However the second guideline here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368772(v=vs.85).aspx

recommends instead a type 19 custom action to check the Privileged is set:

and there is an example here, scroll down:

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Help-on-type-19-custom-action-td712797.html

However, and again, if you need the install to be elevated use InstallPriviges=elevated in your Package element.

Comment: Please share some example

Comment: Hi PhilDW , I have used your comments. Is not working for me , please share me some samples.